# Can I clear an external variable inside a using block?

Tags: c#, idisposable

I have a static StreamWriter field for a log file I need to access through a lambda function that listens to StandardOutput on a long-running Process.

I'm using the null/not-null status of the field to determine if the Process is busy on another thread; the actions need to be performed sequentially.

My question is, what happens when I set my variable to **null** inside a using block? Will it still get disposed properly?

```
public class Service
{
    private static StreamWriter logger;

    void Run(string logFile)
    {
        using (logger = new StreamWriter(logFile))
        {
            /* ... */

            logger = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It will work but it's not recommended.

Comment: And it might not be thread-safe.

Comment: But internally, does the compiler hold a different kind of reference to the object inside the using() parentheses? Or does it remember my field's name and go against that when it's ready to call Dispose()?

Comment: There's only 1 kind of reference, the `using(){}` just makes a copy.

Comment: My mistake; clearly the same 'kind of' reference. I should have left that phrase out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the C# reference, § 8.13, your code:

```
private static StreamWriter logger;

using (logger = new StreamWriter(logFile))
{
   /* ... */
   logger = null;
}
```

is equivalent to

```
private static StreamWriter logger;


{  // using scope
   logger = new StreamWriter(logFile);
   IDisposable resource = logger;       // hidden var inserted by the compiler 
   try
   {
     /* ... */
     logger = null;
   }
   finally
   {
      if (resource != null)  
        resource.Dispose();
   }
}
```

The relevant quote:

> A using statement of the form

```
    using (expression) statement
```

> has the same three possible expansions, but in this case ResourceType is implicitly the compile-time type of the expression, and the resource variable is inaccessible in, and invisible to, the embedded statement.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is, what happens when I set my variable to **null** inside a using block? Will it still get disposed properly?

That depends on where your variable's declared. It will either be disposed of correctly, or your code won't compile in the first place.

## If your variable is declared outside the using statement: Yes

```
A a;
using (a = new A())
{
    a = null;
}
```

Yes, it will be disposed properly. For a simple test:

[image: A variable is nulled within a using block and disposed of successfully]
<sup>My text colour scheme is [Ragnarok Grey](http://studiostyl.es/schemes/ragnarok-grey).</sup>

Even with the assignment cleared, a reference to the `new A()` seems to have been maintained. `a` is disposed of at the end of the `using` statement as expected, even if it's nulled inside.

In some versions of Visual Studio, this may result in [Compiler Warning (level 2) CS0728](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhdyhfk6(v=vs.90).aspx):

> Possibly incorrect assignment to local 'a' which is the argument to a using or lock statement. The Dispose call or unlocking will happen on the original value of the local.

## If your variable declared within the using statement: N/A

```
using (var a = new A())
{
    a = null;
}
```

The above code won't compile. You're not permitted to assign to a `using` variable in the first place. The above code produces this compile error:

> Cannot assign to 'a' because it is a 'using variable'

This is [Compiler Error CS1656](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(CS1656);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5)&rd=true).

> This error occurs when an assignment to variable occurs in a read-only context. Read-only contexts include **foreach** iteration variables, **using** variables, and fixed variables. To resolve this error, avoid assignments to a statement variable in **using** blocks, **foreach** statements, and **fixed** statements.

Comment: Good answer. These compiler writers... they're a clever bunch!

Comment: But the Op declares logger _before_ the using statement. His code will compile with just a warning.

Comment: @Henk Edited. Thanks for pointing this out. I didn't notice that, wow. The two have very different results.

Comment: You may want to include the warning as well, it holds the clue to why it still works.

Comment: @Henk The first example actually produces no warnings for me at all in VS2012 and VS2010! (If you're getting a compiler warning, that is actually concerning. Why am I not seeing one?)

Comment: I didn't see a warning in my compile either. My static **logger** *is* predefined (which I didn't show) with null in the declaration.

Comment: @JBryanPrice Yeah, I just figured I'd cover both options for future readers. Henk pointed out the situation for me - don't worry, you showed clearly that you'd predefined the logger as null. :)

Comment: I get this warning: `Warning 1 Possibly incorrect assignment to local 'logger' which is the argument to a using or lock statement. The Dispose call or unlocking will happen on the original value of the local.`

Comment: @Henk Thanks, I've mentioned that in my answer. It seems the later versions of visual studio might not produce that warning!

Answer (score 2):

This is not a problem.  You'd have to look at the IL with ildasm.exe to see how the compiler does this.  But it generates an extra variable to store a reference to the object so you cannot shoot your foot like this.  The equivalent C# code would (roughly) look like this:

```
StreamWriter $temp = new StreamWriter(logFile);
logger = $temp;
try {
   // etc...
   logger = null;
}
finally {
   if ($temp != null) $temp.Dispose();
}
```

That extra $temp variable keeps you out of trouble.

Comment: +1 Great answer. Thanks for explaining why it works this way!

Comment: Thanks! Does it really grab my IDisposable reference *before* assigning it to my variable? (Just a side question)

Comment: Yes, it really does.  Don't hesitate to play with ildasm.exe

Comment: Interesting: I'm looking at the ILSpy decompile and it appears to set logger first, then the hidden local variable. I'd expect that, since my using may have more a complicated IDisposable-generating expression. But thanks for pointing me at looking at the IL code.

Comment: And for the record, I'm more than capable of shooting myself in the foot. Just not this way, apparently :)